# Simple Apex class to return a list of strings

Tags: apex

I'm writing a simple Apex class as part of the new Salesforce Trailhead developer course. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Create an Apex class that returns an array (or list) of formatted strings ('Test 0', 'Test 1', ...). The length of the array is determined by an integer parameter.

- The Apex class must be called 'StringArrayTest' and be in the public scope.
- The Apex class must have a public static method called 'generateStringArray'.
- The 'generateStringArray' method must return an array (or list) of strings. Each string must have a value in the format 'Test n' where n is the index of the current string in the array. The number of returned strings is specified by the integer parameter to the 'generateStringArray' method.

Here is my code:

```
public class StringArrayTest {

    //Public Method
    public static void generateStringArray(Integer length) {

        //Instantiate the list
        String[] myArray = new List<String>(length);

        //Iterate throught the list
        for(Integer i=0;i<myArray.size();i++) {

            //Populate the array
            myArray.add(myArray[i]);

            // Write value to the debug log
            System.debug(myArray[i]);

        } //end loop

    }//end method       
 }// end class
```

I'm sure it's something very simple I'm doing wrong. When I execute right now it's returning:

> expecting a semi-colon, found ''

Comment: when you write a method that must return something(in your case a list of strings), you do not make it `void`. Change it to `String[]` or `List<String>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't instantiate a [`List`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_constructors) like that using an integer. You don't need to explicitly specify how much items are going into the list when it is created. Instead, just remove the integer:

```
//Instantiate the list
String[] myArray = new List<String>();
```

You're logic in your loop seems to be incorrect as well. Specifically, `myArray`'s size will always be 0 when you instantiate it. Change your loop logic to:

```
for(Integer i=0;i<length;i++) {
   // code
}
```

You want to generate a List of strings based on the `i` variable. You will want to change your internal logic to:

```
//Populate the array
myArray.add('Test ' + i);

// Write value to the debug log
System.debug(myArray[i]);
```

Finally, you want to return that Array. You need to change your method so the return type is no longer `void` by changing its signature:

```
public static String[] generateStringArray(Integer length)
```

then it is just a matter of `return`ing that array at the end of your method:

```
return myArray;
```

This would bring it all together as:

```
public class StringArrayTest {
    //Public Method
    public static String[] generateStringArray(Integer length) {
        //Instantiate the list
        String[] myArray = new List<String>();

        //Iterate throught the list
        for(Integer i=0;i<length;i++) {
            //Populate the array
            myArray.add('Test ' + i);

            // Write value to the debug log
            System.debug(myArray[i]);
        } //end loop

        return myArray;
    }//end method       
}// end class
```

---

Some more info on [Arrays and Lists](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex4_3.htm), [Loops](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops.htm), and [Class methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm) for future reference.

Comment: Right. But his loop would then end immediately as there's not much to loop over. I think the core of the class needs some basic rethinking

Comment: Yep, good call @FrankZ. I realized that after I posted it. I solved the first problem, but that immediately led to another.

Comment: Just like I forgot to return a List of Strings - and not just me :-)

Comment: I just stumbled across this on the active list, and I noticed that this answer is slightly incorrect. You *can* specify the number of initial elements, which has a very minor performance benefit. The correct syntax uses the square brackets (`new String[length];`). This reduces the number of heap allocations that occur, which can improve performance.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is on the following line

```
String[] myArray = new List<String>(length);
```

Lists in Apex do not have constructor for creating lists of predefined length ([see doc](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_constructors)). 
This should solve the problem:

```
String[] myArray = new List<String>();
```

P.S. to satisfy your requirements, you will also have to change for-loop condition like this:

```
for(Integer i=0;i<length;i++) {
```

Comment: They sort of do have a constructor for creating lists of a predefined length. You go: `String[] myArray = new String[length];`

Answer (score 4):

Here's my shot at it:

```
public class StringArrayTest {

    //Public Method
    public static List<String> generateStringArray(Integer length) {

        //Instantiate the list
        List<String> myArray = new List<String>();

        //Iterate throught the list
        for(Integer i=0;i<length;i++) {

            //Populate the array
            myArray.add('Test ' + i);

            // Write value to the debug log
            System.debug(myArray[i]);

        } //end loop

        return myArray;

    }//end method       
 }// end class
```

Comment: You are missing **_The 'generateStringArray' method must return an array (or list) of strings_**

Comment: @FrankZ you need to change it from a void method

Comment: @JesseAltman true. I fixed it and tested the class now.

Answer (score 1):

One thing missed from the above answers . ..

Arrays are zero based you need to **subtract one from the input variable or start the loop from 1.**

Unless that is taken into account when passing in the data.

If the input (length) is 4

```
 public static List<String> generateStringArray(Integer length)
```

..

```
   for(Integer i=0;i<length;i++) {

        //Populate the array
        myArray.add('Test ' + i);

        // Write value to the debug log
        System.debug(myArray[i]);
    }
```

The array size will be 5. so the output will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
   for(Integer i=0;i<length -1 ;i++) {

        //Populate the array
        myArray.add('Test ' + i);

        // Write value to the debug log
        System.debug(myArray[i]);
    }
```

array size is 4, and the output 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of initial elements, which can provide a speed benefit for large arrays. Here's the modified version:

```
public class StringArrayTest {
    public static String[] generateStringArray(Integer length) {
        String[] results = new String[length];
        for(Integer i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            results[i] = 'Test '+i;
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking too...