# Cannot Return a List of Strings - Void method must not return a value

Tags: apex, trailhead, compile-error

I've been using the notes from [Simple Apex class to return a list of strings](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55941/simple-apex-class-to-return-a-list-of-strings). I am having trouble getting this code to work. I'm writing a simple `Apex Class` as part of the Trailhead module **[Getting Started with Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/force_com_dev_beginner/apex_database/apex_database_intro)**. Here's what I'm trying to do:

> Create an Apex class that returns an array (or list) of formatted
>   strings ('Test 0', 'Test 1', ...). The length of the array is
>   determined by an integer parameter.
>
> 1. The Apex class must be called 'StringArrayTest' and be in the public
>      scope.
> 2. The Apex class must have a public static method called
>      'generateStringArray'.
> 3. The 'generateStringArray' method must return an
>      array (or list) of strings. Each string must have a value in the
>      format 'Test n' where n is the index of the current string in the
>      array.  The number of returned strings is specified by the integer
>      parameter to the 'generateStringArray' method.

**Code**

```
public class StringArrayTest {
    // Public Method
    public static void generateStringArray (Integer length) {
        // Instantiate the list
        String[] myArray = new List<String>();

        // Iterate through the list
        for(Integer i=0;i<length;i++) {
            // Populate the array
            myArray.add('Test ' + i);

            // Write value to debug the log
            System.debug(myArray[i]);
        } // end loop

        return myArray;
    } // end method
} // end class
```

**Error Message**

> Void method must not return a value

Comment: A fine first question, and an excellent example of a good question involving trailhead. +1 from me.

Answer (score 7):

You declared your return type as `void`. Change it to `List<String>`.

**Incorrect**

```
public static void generateStringArray
```

**Correct**

```
public static List<String> generateStringArray
```

It would be worth your time to read up on [Class Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm):

> To define a method, specify the following:
>
> - Optional: Modifiers, such as public or protected.
> - Required: The data type of the value returned by the method, such as String or Integer. Use void if the method does not return a value.
> - Required: A list of input parameters for the method, separated by commas, each preceded by its data type, and enclosed in parentheses (). If there are no parameters, use a set of empty parentheses. A method can only have 32 input parameters.
> - Required: The body of the method, enclosed in braces {}. All the code for the method, including any local variable declarations, is contained here.
>     Use the following syntax when defining a method:
>
> ```
> [public | private | protected | global] [override] [static] data_type method_name 
> (input parameters) 
> {
> // The body of the method
> }
> ```

It is your `data_type` that you have incorrectly specified as `void` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
public static void generateStringArray
```

Write

```
public static list<String> generateStringArray
```

Because here void is a return type of that function hence the function returns nothing as per the line return so as to return a value the type of the value needed to be returned needs to be specified in the place of void